# curl (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 37

Tags: curl, cmd, shell

Пытаюсь настроить в телеграмме ввожу все ровно так же как и в уроке по вебхукам, и у меня ошибка

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application
```

Что я ввожу:

```
curl --location --request POST "https://api.telegram.org/bot2130551494:AAHeWgyWJkgZcuyI-n2ReHx-VfQWY9h7k9Q/setWebhook" --header 'Content-Type:application/json' --data-raw '{"url": "https://c33b-146-158-30-117.ngrok.io"}'
```

И в чём я не прав?

Comment: `{"ok":true,"result":true,"description":"Webhook was set"}` — упс :-)

Comment: Таки куда вводишь и при чём тут питон?

Comment: @AlexeyTen в cmd, потому что нужно для телеграмм бота на питоне  + flask

Comment: @AlexeyTen В какой вы терминал вписывали комманду?

Comment: В bash в ubuntu

Comment: Если я правильно помню, то в cmd какая-то беда с одинарными кавычками, но в винде я не силён

Answer (score 1):

Исправил. На Windows cmd не принимает одинарные ковычки, поэтому пишите так:

```
curl --location --request POST "https://api.telegram.org/bot2130551494:AAHeWgyWJkgZcuyI-n2ReHx-VfQWY9h7k9Q/setWebhook" --header 'Content-Type:application/json' --data-raw "{\"url\": \"https://c33b-146-158-30-117.ngrok.io\"}"
```